# Changing Videos on Button Click (multiple Buttons)

Tags: javascript, button, video, onclick

I am trying to change a video with various other options, the idea is the user clicks the button of the video they want to watch and it replaces the current one in the video area.

I want to do this with a simple java script as more videos will be added later on so i don't want to include a whole bunch of links in a java script. I was hoping to use a this function of some sort but i assume my knowledge in this area isn't up to speed yet.

Can anyone help solve this please?

HTML

```
<button onClick="changevid(vid/Video1.mp4)">Video 1</button>
<button onClick="changevid(vid/Video2.mp4)">video 2</button>
<button onClick="changevid(vid/Video3.mp4)">Video 3</button>
<button onClick="changevid(vid/Video4.mp4)">video 2</button>

<video controls>
  <source src="vid/Video1.mp4" id="change" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

JS

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function changevid(){ 

document.getElementById('change').src = buttonlink;

}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pass url as string

`<button onClick="changevid('vid/Video1.mp4')">Video 1</button>`

2. function must receive the argument

`function changevid(buttonLink) {`

3. **id** attribute should be on the **video** tag

`<video controls id="change">
  <source src="vid/Video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>`

http://jsfiddle.net/3dp8khg3/

Comment: Thank you, i tried everything but looks like I missed out the ('vid/video1.mp4') quotes and did not think of moving the id.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple videos with multiple buttons use below simply

Html

```
<video id="vid" controls autoplay style="width:75%">
    <source id="src" src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video><br/><br/>
 <button id="change1">video1</button>
 <button id="change2">video2</button>
 <button id="change3">video3</button>
    
  
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
 const v = document.getElementById("vid");
 const s = document.getElementById("src");
 
 function changeVideo1() { 
    s.src = 'video1.mp4';
    v.load();
    v.play();
 }

 function changeVideo2() { 
    s.src = 'video2.mp4';
    v.load();
    v.play();
 }
 function changeVideo3() { 
    s.src = 'video3.mp4';
    v.load();
    v.play();
 }
 
 document.getElementById("change1").onclick=changeVideo1;       
 document.getElementById("change2").onclick=changeVideo2; 
 document.getElementById("change3").onclick=changeVideo3; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that I can think of to do this. Your method is valid but just needs some adjustment to work.

To get your method to work firstly you need to change your `changeVid` method to take a parameter otherwise you will not be able to pass the video link/id to the method.

So change

```
function changevid(){
```

to

```
function changevid(buttonLink){
```

and then the line;

```
document.getElementById('change').src = buttonLink;
```

will actually work as `buttonLink` now has a value.

One final change is to wrap your video locations in quotes ' ' in order for them to pass through to the changevid method as a string.

so

```
<button onClick="changevid(vid/Video1.mp4)">Video 1</button>
```

becomes

```
<button onClick="changevid('vid/Video1.mp4')">Video 1</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this works but only when i move the id=change to the video tag

Comment: Yes I just noticed that from @augustine response. I find that interesting behaviour but it works so great!